# Search for content between parenthesis in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, indexof

I want to find text just only inside (), but indexOf return full key value

```
var str = "some textsome textsome text(texttext)some text"
var arrSplit = str.split(' ')
for(var i = 0; i < arrSplit.length; i++){
    if(arrSplit[i].indexOf('(') >= 0) {
        console.log(arrSplit[i])
    }
}
```

result

> text(texttext)some

I need

> (texttext)

Comment: Well your code splits on spaces, and there aren't spaces around the parentheses.

Comment: @Pointy yes, I tryed another ways, but this is almost that I need, just need modernize a bit :)

Comment: ... Or use a regex: `var result = str.match(/\(.*?\)/g);` where `result` is an array of all the matches (or `null` if nothing is matched).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes, this is the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To do it only using `split()` (provided there is only one such pattern in the string):

```
str.split('(')[1].split(')')[0]
```

..and using RegEx:

```
str.match(/\([a-z]*\)/ig)        // returns array containing all matches
```

Comment: Your code is correct, but he found only one coincidence. Sorry, but I forgot mention about  many coincidence

Comment: @Tard Use the 2nd then

Answer (score 1):

Try a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
str.match(/\([A-Za-z]*\)/g); // will match all occurrences
```

You can add more the the part in `[]` depending on what you need to match. For example, `0-9` if you want to include numbers. Just avoid using `.*` instead, because this will match something like `"(test) nope! (test)"` as one block.

Essentially, the gist of this regex is that you want all upper/lower case letters between parenthesis. The parentheses has to be escaped (hence `\(` instead of `(`) because parentheses represent grouping in a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try `\(.*?\)` (`RegEx`).

```js
var str = "some textsome textsome text(texttext)some text"
str = str.match(/\(.*?\)/);
console.log(str[0]);
```

**OR** apply in your implementation:

```js
var str = "some textsome textsome text(texttext)some text"
var arrSplit = str.split(' ')
for(var i = 0; i < arrSplit.length; i++){
    if(arrSplit[i].indexOf('(') >= 0) {
        var res = arrSplit[i].match(/\(.*?\)/);
        console.log(res[0])
    }
}
```